# react + react-bootstrap. is it better to create function or fine to write function as a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking at the react-bootstrap components site, and specifically the `<FormControl>` component.

For validating whether the input value is OK, is it acceptable to write it inline or as a function?

For example,

```
<FormControl
  onChange={() => {this.setState({ /* do some ternary check here */ })}
/>
```

I've noticed in a lot of tutorials that authors will either move a lot of these out to functions (ie. `onChange={this.doSomething}`), or sometimes it seems to make sense to do them the way above.

How can I know which way is preferable?

Comment: If your inline handler contains a lot of code, then its best to make it separate otherwise you can do right here. There is no strict rule for it.

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks!.  So it seems like a personal choice then?  Also just one more question on `this.state`.. In order to return a new array (for immutability), is an operation like `Object.keys(this.state).map(i => /* do something*/)` bad?  I am reading the mozilla documentation and I am not sure if this will mutate the `this.state`.

Answer (score 1):

If by using a `ternary operator` you can validate the `input` field then write it inline, and if you want to check many conditions and want to do some computation then better to write a `function` and put all the logic inside that.

Basically function is used to make your code more **structured and readable**, lets say you want to check 3 conditions so if you write those conditions inline then it will become little messy, and unnecessary it will increase the size of `render` part, *try to keep render as small as possible*, because `render` is the starting point of your component, if someone wants check your code, he will start from `render` so it will help him to understand the logic easily.

One more benefit with writing function is, you can use that with other input fields of same type also.

Answer (score 0):

it's good to add a function or make a function.
It would be preferable because using function that function can be called anywhere anytime you wanted but if you use inline then every time you have to write the same thing which makes the code even more complex and clumpsy